# ASP.NET Multiple route and invalid dataroute values

Tags: asp.net, routes

I have multiple routes which refer to different controllers and a few of routes have identical number of parameter. please look at my sample below

```
routes.MapRoute("AdInfo", "{controller}/{action}/{AdGUID}/{UserID}/{Category}",
    new
    {
        controller = "Home",
        action = "DetailAd",
        AdGUID = UrlParameter.Optional,
        UserID = UrlParameter.Optional,
        Category = UrlParameter.Optional
    });   

routes.MapRoute("PostAd", "{controller}/{action}/{MainCategory}/{SubCategory}/{SubCategoryGUID}",
    new
    {
        controller = "Classified",
        action = "Post",
        MainCategory = UrlParameter.Optional,
        SubCategory = UrlParameter.Optional,
        SubCategoryGUID = UrlParameter.Optional
    });
```

Routes AdInfo and PostAd have three parameters but both of them refer to different controller and action. asp.net mvc interpret wrongly, when i click URL which are suppose to link to Controller Classified - action post with route data values MainCategory, subcategory, and subcategoryGUID. somehow, the route data values are AdGUID,UserID,and category.

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, basically you're creating a catch all route and specifying the default, except you have two catchall routes setup. It should be like this at the very least:

```
routes.MapRoute("AdInfo", "Home/{action}/{AdGUID}/{UserID}/{Category}",
    new
    {
        controller = "Home",
        action = "DetailAd",
        AdGUID = UrlParameter.Optional,
        UserID = UrlParameter.Optional,
        Category = UrlParameter.Optional
    });   

routes.MapRoute("PostAd", "Classified/{action}/{MainCategory}/{SubCategory}/{SubCategoryGUID}",
    new
    {
        controller = "Classified",
        action = "Post",
        MainCategory = UrlParameter.Optional,
        SubCategory = UrlParameter.Optional,
        SubCategoryGUID = UrlParameter.Optional
    });
```

Of course in some situations this won't work. The only way I can see being able to use this route for multiple controllers too is by adding a suffix after the controller like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("AdInfo", "{Controller}/{action}/SomeNameThatSeperatesThisRouteFromTheNext/{AdGUID}/{UserID}/{Category}",
```

Or if on the second route the action will always be the same, then just hard code it into the route and now you will have two distinct routes (Make sure the route you hard code is declared before the other route).